# Fundamental vs true RMS values - Can the fundamental be higher than true RMS

Tags: harmonics

Here is a practical situation: We are measuring harmonics with a Class-A PQ device. At certain times we have the fundamental values of current **higher** than the true RMS values. I would like to know if such phenomena can happen and in what situation.

Comment: if you're measuring peak values, obviously they can exceed RMS values for the same quantity.

Comment: For sine signal the peaks are *always* higher than RMS...

Comment: The RMS is effectively a measurement of power. Power is non-negative. The total power of a signal will always be the sum of its components, and each component will be no larger than the total. If a component measures more than the total, this indicates a problem with the measurement, not new physics or new maths.

Comment: Are you sure that the Class-A  PQ is "well-calibrated" device ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\text{RMS of a signal} = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2+C^2 + D^2+...}$$

So, no matter what value you ascribe to B, C and D harmonic amplitudes, the RMS of a harmonically distorted signal can never be less than the RMS of the A quantity (or B quantity etc.). See [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square#In_waveform_combinations) for the RMS of waveform combinations: -

[image]